# Javascript - Replacing a part of string within special characters

Tags: javascript

I have 2 javascript variables that has values:

```
var Name = 'John';
var Age = '14';
```

and another string variable that looks like this:

```
var message = 'I am **Name** and my age is **Age**';
```

How can I inject the value of `Name` and `Age` variables into the `message` string to replace the `**Name**` and `**Age**` with values 'John' and '14'?

```
var newmessage = 'I am John and my age is 14';
```

Is there a javascript function I can use to perform this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method and get variable from `window` object (only works when the variable is defined in the global context other ways you need to use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) method which I don't prefer to use.).

```js
var Name = 'John';
var Age = '14';
var message = 'I am **Name** and my age is **Age**';
var newmessage = message.replace(/\*\*([\w\d]+)\*\*/g, function(m, m1) {
  return window[m1];
});

console.log(newmessage)
```

---

Or use an object instead of variables for storing the value so you can get value easily even it's not defined in global context.

```js
var obj = {
  Name: 'John',
  Age: '14'
};
var message = 'I am **Name** and my age is **Age**';
var newmessage = message.replace(/\*\*([\w\d]+)\*\*/g, function(m, m1) {
  return obj[m1];
});

console.log(newmessage)
```

Comment: why window object . what is `_`  ?

Comment: @Mahi :  you can access global variable from `window` object

Comment: @Mahi : `_` is an argument.... since we just need the captured value we can avoid that.... so I just used `_`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thank you, this is what I really need since I can have more than the stated number of variables. I can select this as the answer in 3mins. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Try with simple [string.replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function

```js
var Name = 'John';
var Age = '14';
var message = 'I am **Name** and my age is **Age**';
message = message.replace('**Name**' ,Name).replace('**Age**' , Age);
console.log(message)
```

Comment: simpler than pranav answer

Comment: I would've selected this as the answer for simplicity if the number of replacing variables is fixed like the one used here (sorry I have not mentioned in my post that I can have more)

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution. Checking **FIRST** if those subStrings are actually part of the string message. Hope it helps!

```js
var Name = 'John';
var Age = '14';

var message = "I am **Name** and my age is **Age**";
console.log(myFunction(message));

function myFunction(str){
  var finalMessage = "";
  if(str.indexOf("**Name**") !== -1){
     finalMessage = str.replace('**Name**' ,Name);
  }
  if(finalMessage.indexOf("**Age**") !== -1){
     finalMessage = finalMessage.replace("**Age**" ,Age);
  }
  return finalMessage;
}
```

Comment: if i removed `e` from Name . it returns empty string

Comment: @Mahi I know, but he said replace text **Name** for John, he never mentioned about removing e